# Rule of thumb to begin optimizing a page's database queries

Tags: database

I'm implementing database profiling in a website that will definitely start seeing a measured increase in growth over the next year.  I'm implementing query profiling on each page (using Zend) and am going to log issues when a page gets too slow.  At that point, I'll see what I can do to optimize the queries.  The problem, is that without any experience with scaling a website, I'm not sure what "too slow" would be for the queries on a given page.  Is there any accepted time-limit for the queries on a given page before one should look for ways to optimize the queries?

Thanks,

Eric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no global "too slow". Everything depends on what the queries do and what's your traffic like. Invest some time in writing scenarios for a traffic generator and just load-test your website. Check which parts break first, fix them and repeat. Even the simple queries can hit some pathological cases.

Don't forget to load more fake data into the database too - more users are likely to generate more data for you and some problems may start only when the dataset is larger than your database caching/buffers. Make sure you're blaming the right queries too - if you have something locking the tables for update, other transactions may need retries / get delayed - look at the top N queries instead of fixating on one single query.

Make sure you look at the queries from both sides too - from the client and the server. If you're using mysql for example, you can easily log all queries which don't use indexes for joins / searches. You can also use [percona toolkit](http://www.percona.com/software/percona-toolkit) (previously Maatkit) to grab the traffic off the network and analyse that instead. You can use [mysqltunner](http://mysqltuner.pl) to see how many cache misses you experience. For other databases, you can find similar tools elsewhere.

If there is any general rule, I'd say - if your queries start taking 10x the time they took without any other load, you've got a problem. Also, it's not about queries - it's about page load time. Find an answer to "how long should the page generation take?" and go from there. (probably less than a second unless you do heavy data processing under the covers)

Comment: Thank you for a very thorough answer!